# Get Array Value In Table

Tags: php

Given below is my  $Array. Empty part shows no files in folder:

```
    Array
(
    [16A] => Array
        (
            [2014-2015] => Array
                (
                    [Q1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ../webroot/files/16A/2014-2015/Q1/AAAAA2005Q_Q1_AY201415_16A.pdf
                        )

                    [Q2] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [Q3] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [Q4] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )   


            [2016-2017] => Array
                (
                    [Q1] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [Q2] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [Q3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ../webroot/files/16A/2016-2017/Q3/AAAAA2005Q_Q3_AY201617_16A.pdf
                            [1] => ../webroot/files/16A/2016-2017/Q3/AAACB6215D_Q3_AY201617_16A.pdf
                            [2] => ../webroot/files/16A/2016-2017/Q3/AAACB7821R_Q3_AY201617_16A.pdf
                            [3] => ../webroot/files/16A/2016-2017/Q3/AAACC6356N_Q3_AY201617_16A.pdf
                            [4] => ../webroot/files/16A/2016-2017/Q3/AAACE7722Q_Q3_AY201617_16A.pdf
                        )



                )

        )
```

I want to show it in html table :
[image]

I tried below code but it's not working with data table so any other option or logic.

```
<?php foreach ($Array as $key => $value) { ?>

            <?php foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) { ?>
                <tr class="active">
                <?php if($value2){?>
                  <td><?php echo $key ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $key1 ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $key2 ?></td>
                  <td><?php if($value2){
                                $array = explode('/', $value2[0]);echo $array[count(explode('/', $value2[0])) -1];} ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } }?>
            <?php }?>
        <?php }?>
```

Thank you for seeing my question. It will be great help if you will give me answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php foreach ($Array as $key => $value){ ?>
        <?foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1){?>
            <?foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2){?>
                <? if ($value2){ ?>
                    <tr class="active">
                        <td><?=$key ?></td>
                        <td><?=$key1 ?></td>
                        <td><?=$key2 ?></td>
                        <td><?if ($value2)
                            {
                                $array = explode('/', $value2[0]);
                                echo $array[count(explode('/', $value2[0])) - 1];
                            } ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?}
            }
        }
     }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
$array = explode('/', $value2[0]);
echo $array[count($array) -1];
```

Comment: my code already working but it gives me error with datatables : unknow parameter 0 for raw 1 in datatable.